# Model Binding in mvc core Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a POCO class with this definition

```
public class IndOff
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Member Name")]
    [Required]
    public int MemberID { get; set; }
    public OfferingType OfferingType { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Offering Type")]
    [Required]
    public int OfferingTypeID { get; set; }

    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Currency")]
    [Required]
    public int CurrencyID { get; set; }
    public Member Member { get; set; }

    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

}
```

Then i defined a View Model on this class as

```
public class IndOffViewModel
{
    public IndOffViewModel()
    {

    }
    public IEnumerable<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OfferingType> OfferingTypes { get; set; }
    public Member Member { get; set; }
    public IndOff IndOff { get; set; }
}
```

From my controller, the view to capture data is rendered correctly, the problem occurs when i post data. 
My post action is

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Save(IndOff model, int memberId)
    {
        model.Date = DateTime.Today;
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var member = _context.Members.Single(m => m.Id == memberId);
            var viewModel = new IndOffViewModel
            {
                Member = member,
                Currencies = _context.Currencies.ToList(),
                OfferingTypes = _context.OfferingTypes.ToList()
            };
            return View("IndForm", viewModel);
        }
        if (model.Id == 0)
            _context.IndOffs.Add(model);
        else
        {
            var dbIndOff = _context.IndOffs.Single(c => c.Id == model.Id);
            dbIndOff.Amount = model.Amount;
            dbIndOff.CurrencyID = model.CurrencyID;
            dbIndOff.OfferingTypeID = model.OfferingTypeID;
            //dbIndOff.WorshipCenterID = weekOff.WorshipCenterID;
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("New", new { id = model.Id});
    }
```

However, the IndOff model object passed is always empty with nulls for the properties. Though when i use chrome inspector, i see that the values has been passed to the controller.
What's the problem or what am i doing wrong? This is how the View page looks like

```
@model ViewModels.IndOffViewModel
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Offering";
}
<form asp-action="Save" method="post">
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="IndOff.OfferingTypeID" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="IndOff.OfferingTypeID" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.OfferingTypes,"ID","Name"))" class="form-control">
        <option value="">-Select-</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="IndOff.OfferingTypeID" class="text-danger" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="IndOff.CurrencyID" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="IndOff.CurrencyID" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Currencies,"Id","Name"))" class="form-control">
        <option value="">-Select-</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="IndOff.CurrencyID" class="text-danger" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="IndOff.Amount" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="IndOff.Amount" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="IndOff.Amount" class="text-danger" />
</div>
@*<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input asp-for="Member.Baptised" />
        Baptised ?
    </label>
</div>*@
<input type="hidden" asp-for="IndOff.Id" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Member.Id" name="memberId" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: i think the issue is that the memberid is not part of the model

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: You need to show your view!

Comment: Have added view page now

Comment: The model in your view is `IndOffViewModel` which means the parameter in your POST method also need to be `IndOffViewModel model` (not `IndOff` model). And why do you have a separate parameter for `int memberId`? (you already have a property in `IndOff` for `MemberID`)

Comment: Yes, I tried passing IndOffViewModel, still same nulls, It should still work for you can pass a subset of a class or the entire class to post, The form properties when you inspect with chrome inspector are like indOff.CurrencyId, indOff.OfferingTypeID, so just passing indOff should work out of the box. I added memberID as a way to test.

Comment: Because your posting `indOff.CurrencyId: someValue` etc your POST method **must** be `public ActionResult Save(IndOffViewModel model)` because `IndOffViewModel` contains a property named `indOff` (but `IndOff` does not contain a property named `indOff` so binding would fail)` The values will not be `null` unless you have made other mistakes as well. Although you can use the `Prefix` property of `BindAttribute` but that's unnecessary if your design was correct in the first place (do **not** use data models when editing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `IndOff` class in contained inside of the `IndOffViewModel`, you need to give the action a "hint" about where to start looking using the `Bind` attribute. Like so:

```
public ActionResult Save([Bind(Prefix="IndOff")]IndOff model, int memberId)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, by adding the prefix, it works now. However, i still want to ask why my other viewmodels and saving works out of the box but i needed to add this. Have several other viewmodels like that. They all work without the Bind. Can you help explain it for me?

Comment: I'd be happy to, however I'm not sure we can fit all that info in the comments section :). Do you want to update your question with those examples? Alternatively, you can create another question and let me know.

Comment: please take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39579183/model-binding-in-mvc-core)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use your ViewModel to generate your form?
In that case, the binding won't work because the path to the propertis doesn't match.

The html input tag's id will be "IndOff.{fieldName}".

But your controller take IndOff and not IndOffViewModel as parameter.
The path to IndOff's properties is then "{fieldnName}".

To solve this binding issue, your ViewModel could extend IndOff instead of containing the IndOff property.