# Model Binding in MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 viewmodels in my project defined as follows,

```
public class MemberFormViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<WorshipCenter> WorshipCenters { get; set; }
    public Member Member { get; set; }
}
```

Then another one defined as

```
public class NotesFormViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
    public Notes Note { get; set; }
}
```

Then yet another as

```
public class IndOffViewModel
{
    public IndOffViewModel()
    {

    }
    public IEnumerable<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OfferingType> OfferingTypes { get; set; }
    public Member Member { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public IndOff IndOff { get; set; }
}
```

Then my view pages all call save action that presents objects Member, Notes, IndOff for the classes presented.
The action for the MemberViewModel looks like this

```
 public ActionResult Save(Member member)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var viewModel = new MemberFormViewModel
            {
                Member = member,
                WorshipCenters = _context.WorshipCenters.ToList()
            };
            return View("MemberForm", viewModel);
        }
        if (member.Id == 0)
            _context.Members.Add(member);
        else
        {
            var dbMember = _context.Members.Single(c => c.Id == member.Id);
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

MemberViewModel automatically binds to Member object correctly on POST. NotesViewModel also binds nicely to Notes object. 
However, IndOffViewModel does not bind when IndOff object is presented to it. 
Unless [Bind(Prefix = "IndOff")] is presented before the IndOff object.
Can someone please help point me in the right direction as to help me avoid future problems.
The view looks like this

```
@model eChurch.WebUI.ViewModels.MemberFormViewModel
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Member";
}
<h2>Member</h2>
<form asp-action="Save" method="post">
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Member.Name" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Member.Name" class="form-control"/>
    <span asp-validation-for="Member.Name" class="text-danger" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Member.WorshipCenterID" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="Member.WorshipCenterID" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.WorshipCenters,"ID","Name"))" class="form-control">
        <option value="">-Select-</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Member.WorshipCenterID" class="text-danger" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Member.PhoneNumber" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Member.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Member.PhoneNumber" class="text-danger" />
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input asp-for="Member.Baptised" />
        @*<label asp-for="BaseCurrency" class="control-label"></label>*@
        Baptised ?
    </label>
</div>
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Member.Id" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>

@section Scripts {
   @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `MemberViewModel` wil **not** bind to `Member member` unless you have done something wrong in your view. And never use data models when editing - use view models

Comment: Just realized your parameter name is `member` which matches the name of your property which is why it would bind, but this will lead to other issues (and if you changed it to (say) `Member model` it would not bind). Do not name your parameter the same as a property in your model

Comment: @Stephen, thanks for your observation, tried changing the name of the parameter to model to test, it did not bind as you said. Have added the view as well now.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?

Comment: @ShaiCohen, I was able to test based on Stephen Muecke's suggestion. Don't understand it yet. Will still appreciate help on this.